# Swipe dismissing service notification

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-notifications

Thought that wouldn't be a problem at all, but still.
My Service notification doesn't want to swipe-dismiss no matter what I do.

I have a progress notification, that is started in the service using startForeground(id, Notification).
Here is how i build it:

```
public Notification createErrorNotification(String message) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());

    Intent showAppIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    showAppIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    showAppIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    PendingIntent pendingShowAppIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 10,
            showAppIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


    builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.label_download_error))
            .setWhen(0)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentIntent(pendingShowAppIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    return builder.build();
}
```

At some point if error occurs, I replace my progress notification with the described Error notification, disabling 'ongoing' and other stuff.
I also stop service completely:

```
private void stopService() {
    stopSelf();
    taskThread.stopLooper();
    downloadHandler.stopExecution();
    downloadHandler = null;
    taskThread = null;
}
```

And call

```
stopForeground(false);
```

false - because I want notification to be kept on screen and dismissed by user.
But swipe-dismissing simply doesn't work.

If I call stopForeground(true) - notification is correctly removed.

Anyone has any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: after call stopForeground(true), try to update notification, by creating a new one with option setCanceble(true) and same notification id,

Comment: there is no method 'setCancelable' for NotificationCompat.Builder

Comment: As you can see in my code snippet, autoCancel is set

Comment: did you set setAutoCancel to **new** notification, not old?

Comment: Yes, of course. And it still doesn't work as expected

Comment: here how i did this: i call stopForeground(true), cancel notification mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID), and then show new notification with same id, and autocancel set to true

Comment: Good idea, thanks, I'll try this out. I think you can format it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @orium have suggested, to resolve this issue you need to stop the services in foreground mode removing notification, and create a new notification using the same ID, but with settings set to dismissable.
That would be:
stopForegound(true)
and create notification with setAutoCancel(true)

Answer (score 1):

Removing the notification isn't necessary. You can detach it from the service by using:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH);
else
    stopForeground(false);
```

You can then using the notification manager to notify again with the same ID if you need to update any information. The STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH flag will prevent the notification from going away when the service is destroyed on later Android versions. You won't see the notification disappearing and re-appearing like you would after dismissing the first one.

Comment: STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH is only available in API >= 24.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a notification id of 0 for the notification, in which case the delete pending intent of the notification will invoked where you can stop the service.